# How to disable auto-format in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

## Version

- DataGrip 2018.3

---

[image]

When I type ')', it auto-format my sql

[image]

---

Happened after upgraded from version 2018.2

Disable formating is not helping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug which is going to be fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7399

Comment: Alternatively solution: Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys, uncheck "Reformat block on typing '}'".